# NO_DOCUMENT_RECEIVED is getting when we are sending mail by using api

Tags: docusignapi

Using DocuSign API, I am sending an email. but it is giving error as follows.

> status = 400Error calling DocuSign, status is:400 error text: {
>   "errorCode": "NO_DOCUMENT_RECEIVED", "message": "The document element
>   did not contain the encoded document, or there is a problem with the
>   encoding. Bytes for document corresponding to documentId 1 not found
>   in request. 'documentId=' possibly missing from Content-Disposition
>   header." }

We are using sandbox account along with Curl and PHP. Document file I am sending from local drive and what kind of document file can send?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. You should include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm getting status 0 when we are sending mail by using api with docusign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45853593/im-getting-status-0-when-we-are-sending-mail-by-using-api-with-docusign)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using the same request as specified in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45853593/1219543)

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45865919/1219543).

Make sure you are actually providing the document bytes in your request.

Also the file type and `Content-Type` header that you specify should match